# Show dialogue in map overlays

Tags: android

In my application I am using a map overlay. When I click on an overlay image it should display an Android dialog. From that dialog the user can choose from different options. Please help me.

Thank you

Aswan

Answer (score 1):

There's a developer guide section on [creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) that you can follow.

There's also sample code available in the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) sample project bundled with the SDK. Look for [AlertDialogSamples.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html).